PM2 Error Script not found when try to start
This is first time working with casino games using Goldsvet
When I try commands given in the script description such as:
root@host:# pm2 start Arcade.js --watch pm2 start Server.js --watch pm2 start Slots.js --watch
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting /home/..../public_html/PTWebSocket/Arcade.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
[PM2][ERROR] Script not found: /home/..../public_html/PTWebSocket/start

Also in which folder we have to upload game files I have no idea.
Thanks for any help.

check you are running the command in the directory where your Arcade.js file is located in

yes its in the same directory where Arcade.js is
